# safariで一定間隔で自動更新する方法

Tags: macos, safari

MacでSafariを使用していて、ページの読み込みを一定間隔で自動更新するにはどうすればいいでしょぅか。

Answer (score 1):

1. HTMLを自分で書くような場合
   headタグやJavaScriptでリロードさせることができます。詳しくは、
   https://www.mitsue.co.jp/knowledge/blog/frontend/201806/29_1525.html
   などを参照してください。
2. 他のサイトで行いたい場合
   [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/?browser=safari)などを使って、該当ページにJavaScriptを適用することで実現できると思います。JavaScript自体は1.と同じようなものが使えます。対象サイトにあまり負荷がかからないように、リロード間隔や実施時間は控えめにお願いします。

Comment: 自分で制作したページではなく、他の人が作られたページを一定間隔で自動で読み込む場合はどうすればいいでしょうか? できれば参照するという形ではなく、ここにすべて説明を書いていただける方が助かります。

Comment: @user25636 さん、2 がまさにその方法です。

Comment: TamperMonkeyをインストールしてjavascriptのコードはどこに書けばいいのでしょうか?